# Creating a favorite list in PHP

Tags: php

I'm developing a software portal, where users can add a software as favorite and when they do that, the software will get displayed in their profile.

For doing this, I planned to do the following:

There is a separate column named "favorites" in the "users" table. When a user adds a software as a favorite, then the software ID will get added using comma, like

```
"102,405,502,695,595"
```

For displaying I planned to use PHP's explode function and query the software name after that.

My question is: what happens if the user has some 100 favorites? Does it take long time to load the list? Is there any other method to implement this concept?

Comment: bad design. [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables and split the favorites into a separate table. Anything else will just cause you severe headaches later on

Comment: +1 for asking instead of building it wrong.

Comment: The design you propose has an additional problem - searching the data is much more difficult. Normalization will allow you to more easily find the number of people who've favorited something, count the number of total favorites, count a user's, etc.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view it's not ok, not because you have to explode that list every time, because that's ok.

The problem is that every time someone deletes 1 favorite the script has to fetch all that text, explode, remove that id and update again.

You should make that table like `id|user|id_software`, every software with it's own row, then selects, updates and delete will be much faster and easier.

For your answer: nothing happens if you have 1000 favorites, PHP is designed and capable to handle huge amount of data if settings, machine and OS are ok.

Answer (score 1):

Youu can use another table to assign the relationship between user and Software. To use such serialized things in one table is good when there are only a few entries as you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

That is a horrendous was of doing it.

You **must** normalise your tables. If you don't know what normalization is, then you need to read up on it before you start this project.

Basically, you will need three tables.

- Users
- Software
- UsersFavouriteSoftware

Users will have `id`, `username`
Software will have `id`, `softwareName`,
UsersFavouriteSoftware will have a "registry" where you have the join relations.

**Users Table**

```
id | userName
1  | Bob
2  | Alive
```

**Software Table**

```
id | softwareName
1  | Firefox
2  | Chrome
3  | Internet Exploiter
```

**Join Table**

```
userId | softwareId
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 1
```

So user with ID 1 likes Chrome and Internet Exploiter, and you can get this information with a simple join query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't want to limit your users to a maximum number of favorites?

Anyway, i such situations, i create an additional database-table, lokking somehow like

Table FavoritesUserRelations
(int)user_id | (int)software_id

This approach will make your code simpler, if you're going to work with an Fav-Entry, like deleting a Favorite, adding a new one or sorting the for displaying purposes. Also, you're not limited in size, maximum or search statements ...